# numpy subtract every row of matrix by vector

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

So I have a **`n x d`** matrix and an **`n x 1`** vector. I'm trying to write a code to subtract every row in the matrix by the vector.

I currently have a **`for`** loop that iterates through and subtracts the **`i`**-th row in the matrix by the vector. **Is there a way to simply subtract an entire matrix by the vector?**

Thanks!

Current code:

```
for i in xrange( len( X1 ) ):
    X[i,:] = X1[i,:] - X2
```

This is where **`X1`** is the matrix's **`i`**-th row and **`X2`** is vector. Can I make it so that I don't need a **`for`** loop?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

That works in `numpy` but **only if the trailing axes have the same dimension**.  Here is an example of successfully subtracting a vector from a matrix:

```
In [27]: print m; m.shape
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11]]
Out[27]: (4, 3)

In [28]: print v; v.shape
[0 1 2]
Out[28]: (3,)

In [29]: m  - v
Out[29]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [6, 6, 6],
       [9, 9, 9]])
```

This worked because the trailing axis of both had the same dimension (3).

In your case, the leading axes had the same dimension.  Here is an example, using the same `v` as above, of how that can be fixed:

```
In [35]: print m; m.shape
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]
Out[35]: (3, 4)

In [36]: (m.transpose() - v).transpose()
Out[36]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 5, 6],
       [6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

The rules for broadcasting axes are explained in depth [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Comment: `m-v.transpose()` would not work the same in general.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The problem is that a one dimensional array in numpy cannot be transposed, as it will be the same as the output. You have to add a dimension to it to transpose it like in the answer of Nagasaki45 or when creating the np.array with the ndmin=2 argument.

Comment: @xuiqzy. Very good point. I'll delete the comment. Transposing usually copies memory. A better way might be `m - v[:, None]`

Answer (score 21):

In addition to @John1024 answer, "transposing" a one-dimensional vector in numpy can be done like this:

```
In [1]: v = np.arange(3)

In [2]: v
Out[2]: array([0, 1, 2])

In [3]: v = v[:, np.newaxis]

In [4]: v
Out[4]:
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])
```

From here, subtracting `v` from every column of `m` is trivial using broadcasting:

```
In [5]: print(m)
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]

In [6]: m - v
Out[6]:
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 5, 6],
       [6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: FYI, m-v[:, None] also works if you forget the np.newaxis thing. I would argue that this option is simpler yet.

Comment: @ChristianO'Reilly. `np.newaxis is None`. They refer to the same object. At that point it's what the author considers to be more legible.

Answer (score 0):

If you were just creating the vector that gets subtracted, you can also create it with

```
column_vector = np.array([0,1,2], ndmin=2).T
```

to get a column vector, which is only possible if it has dimension 2 or more.
One dimensional numpy arrays are always rows and cannot be transposed!

Then you can just do

```
each_column_of_matrix_minus_vector = matrix - column_vector
```

to subtract `column_vector` from every column of `matrix`.